# Глобальный хук мыши c++ (зажатие)

Tags: c++

Как заставить хук видеть, когда мышь зажата. Написав хук на обработку действий мыши, я мог определить нажатие клавиш, а не зажатие. Тоесть вместо того, чтобы действие выполнялось несколько раз при зажатии, оно выполнялось один раз.

Comment: Получено события нажатия клавиши -> Клавиша зажата. Получено события отжатия клавиши -> Клавиша больше не зажата.

Comment: @user7860670 а как это в коде реализовать

Comment: В вопросе написано *я мог определить нажатие клавиш* - значит уже реализовано.